# Spring MVC unable to map URL's

Tags: java, spring, model-view-controller

I created a spring MVC project, with a controller class having request mapping methods but when I run the project on server it gives me a 404 error (Requested resource not found)
Attached below are the screenshots of my web.xml, idm-servlet.xml and the controller class files.
[image: idm-servlet.xml]

[image: web.xml]

[image: controller.java]

After running the project, the URL remains the same instead of getting changed due to mapping.

[image]

Comment: do you have a /WEB-INF/home.jsp ?

Comment: @clement Since my controller returns "common/loginsuccess", I do have a folder "common" and a file under it,namely, loginsuccess.jsp

Comment: Does Your class where You have method `home()` have annotation `@Controller`?

Comment: The class having the method does have the @controller annotation.

Comment: Your web.xml contains Context Parameter "contextConfigLocation" two times, consolidate them into single entry otherwise second one will override first one.

Answer (score 0):

In the url-pattern of idm servlet you listen to any HTTP requests which ends with ".do"
While your request mapping contains "/home"

I would do change the mapping to "/home.do"

Comment: You are missing some jars in the classpath... see this example http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-hello-world-example/

Answer (score 0):

Please add in `web.xml`:

```
<welcome-file-list>
<welcome-file>home</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

It should help.

Comment: Atleast I'm getting an error after including your code snippet.
But I'm unable to resolve the error.
The screeshot is attached in the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change DispatcherServlet mapping form `*.do` to `/`. Also I think you miss some dependencies(jars).

Comment: Done what you suggested, copied all the jars from the spring dist folder. still not working :(
Same error as in the screenshot.